# Bootstrap Modals and .net C# server response

Tags: c#, .net, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a web application, using .net MVC C#.
I have a bootstrap modal which is a form.
After doing the POST: How can I get the server response into the same modal, for example to validate the errors using .net validator messages.
?

Comment: Yes, I did it with ajax.
In the server I call: return View(model); But in fact the modal is generated but in another page, not in the same.

Comment: can you share the code that you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery validate on modals just the same way you use it on another part of the DOM. Remember to use @Html.EditorFor(...) or similar Razor methods and to link jqueryVal javascript with:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And in your BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```